# Answers tab of new user profile page needs more love

Tags: discussion, user-interface, profile-page

The [new user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live) is now live on Stack Overflow as well. Overall, it looks good, only I'm not sure about the [*answers* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=answers). It's too empty when compared to the [*questions* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=questions) which causes that the line separators on the *answers* tab are much more disturbing than on all other tabs.

There are basically 2 options to fix this:

1. Remove those line separators
2. Or, add more information to each answer.

I tend to adding more information so that it's more nicely in line with the *questions* tab. I'm only not sure what kind of information could be added. Views? Question tags? Timestamps? An excerpt of the 1st paragraph? Referral links? Unicorns?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... On the previous design, they were packed in pretty tight - there *was* some space on the right, but trying to put something in there would have meant *instant* "wall of text".

The new layout is 54% larger vertically, *room for answers to breathe*... So I'd like to see at least the Creation Date listed to the right of each answer.

[image: timestamps shown to the right of answers]

Comment: I would love to see the creation dates as well.